# Reference request for unconstrained optimization

Tags: reference-request

I want to study following topics.

1: Line search iterative methods (The steepest descent method, Newton's method, Quasi-Newton's method),

2:Scalar correction method.

I haven't studied these topics before. Could anybody suggest me references for a beginner?

Thanks

Comment: I think this [link](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~zhang/caam554/KelleyBooks/fr18_book.pdf‎) ought help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to take a look at various introductionary books to numerical analysis. I cannot give you anything specific in English, the only book I used to cover this was in German.

I'd suggest you simply search for some intro. books and see what fits your taste.